# Return to "for" after "if" is executed

Tags: python, function, csv, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to create a program that generates estimates to potential customers.
The idea is that you enter item-Ids and quantities of wanted item/s and the program goes through a database to find and extract matching values, if any.

In the case that there is no match, I want to be able to manually add the details (for the current calculation, not write to database )

I got it all working, *if* the manual process is made at the very end. But since you wouldn't know if an item exists or not beforehand, it's easy to break the program.

I've tried to look all over for a solution before writing this but haven't been able to.
My guess is that I don't fully understand the order of things and/or is missing some basic function to make it work.

The closest I was of finding an explanation was, as I understood it, to somehow create separate functions for the if/else statements and call them separately when appropriate, but I don't know how to implement that in the existing code.

Here's a snippet from the code:

```
    #TRY TO FIND ITEM IN FILE

while totalItems != 0:
    article = input("Search: ")
    totalItems = totalItems - 1

    for row in csv_file:
        if article == row[0]:
            items.append(row[0])
            desc.append(row[1])
            prices.append(float(row[2]))
            qt = input("Quantity: ")
            qt = int(qt)
            qts.append(qt)
            break

    if article != row[0]:
        items.append(article)
        qt = input("Quantity: ")
        qt = int(qt)
        qts.append(qt)
        inputItem = input("Item: ")
        desc.append(inputItem)
        inputPrice = input("Price: ")
        inputPrice = float(inputPrice)
        prices.append(inputPrice)
```

Example snippet if all items exists in database/file:

```
Search: 1821091
Quantity: 5
Search: 1835006
Quantity: 5
Search: 1835017
Quantity: 5
How many % profit?:
```

Example snippet if last item does not exist:

```
Search: 1821091
Quantity: 5
Search: 1835006
Quantity: 5
Search: 0000000
Quantity: 5
Item: Bogus-Product
Price: 80.40
How many % profit?:
```

Example snippet if item that does not exist is added anywhere before last entry:

```
Search: 0000000
Quantity: 5
Item: Bogus-Product
Price: 80.40
Search: 1821091
Quantity: 5
Item: < This should not ask me to add another item...
```

Comment: You cannot just jump around. Your second if should be indented, it should be inside `for` loop anyways...

Comment: I get that there is no "back" option, but in my mind when the second if-statement has ended, it should return to the beginning of the for-loop and try to search for the next input. Instead it continues with the second if-statement again.

If i indent the second "if" nothing works properly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the second if should only be executed if a match hasn't been found. So in the first if block add a flag `found = True` before breaking and then check for that in the second.

Comment: @Reti43

Correct, and it works the first time.But instead of breaking out of the second if, going back to the beginning of the for-loop and ask me for another product ("Search: "), it continues to ask me for a manual input ("Item: ").

I tried to implement flags but couldn't get it to work properly. 

Setup as follows.
Outside of if statements
found = True
|
if found:
--> run first block
else: found = False

|
if not found:
--> run second block
set found = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use key/values to have a better performance when dealing with these lists. Also, always try to reduce the ambiguity of code creating functions to reuse parts that are the same.

You need, for each element, to iterate over all rows and check if it is present. For you initial code, you would need to do a "for" and "break" everytime, while not leaving the while. This gives you the responsibility to handle the finding and the allocation of the elements in the list, if you have the data you need already in a dict, you can easily look for it and use its values to add to your other lists.

```
def add_item(item, description, price): # As you always request for the quantity before adding prices, you can ask it inside the method
            qt = input("Quantity: ")

            items.append(item)
            desc.append(description)
            prices.append(float(price))
            qts.append(int(qt))

...

    csv_list = {}

    for row in csv_reader:
        csv_list.update({row[1]: {"desc": row[0], "price": row[2]}}) # Add each article as being the key in a dictionary and its values with keys for the description and price

    while totalItems != 0:
        article = input("Search: ")
        totalItems = totalItems - 1

        if article in csv_list.keys(): # If the article is in the csv, you just get its values and add to your lists
            values = csv_list[article]
            add_item(article, values["desc"], values["price"])
        else: # If not, you retrieve the item and price to add in your list anyway
            inputItem = input("Item: ")
            inputPrice = input("Price: ")
            add_item(article, inputItem, inputPrice)
```

I hope this helped.

Regards.

Comment: After some tinkering I got it working using your approach! 
Thank you very much for the thorough, instructive help.